# How to Resolve Failed to load config "prettier" to extend from. in react Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am very new to React JS, and now i am using Core-ui template for study purpose.

here im facing the issue like

> Failed to load config "prettier" to extend from.

[image]

[image]

Package.json

```html
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.2"
  }
```

.eslintrc.js

```html
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { endOfLine: 'auto' }], // Use our .prettierrc file as source
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    // 'simple-import-sort/imports': 'error',
    // 'simple-import-sort/exports': 'error',
  },
}
```

Comment: Maybe install the "prettier" extension in vscode?

Comment: Prettier already installed in my vscode.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier).

`npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier`

In your `.eslintrc` you'll need to add "prettier" to the extends array as the last item.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by installing eslint-config-prettier as a dev dependency

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two type of `packages` per say `plugins` and `configs` them plugins go into the plugins section they have all the rules and stuff and the `configs` they go into the `extends` section

```js
module.exports = {
    extends: ["eslint:recommended","eslint-config-prettier"],
    env: {
        node: true,
        commonjs: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    parser: "babel-eslint",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: "module",
        ecmaFeatures: {
            impliedStrict: true,
            jsx: true,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        polyfills: ["promises"],
        "import/resolver": {
            node: {
                moduleDirectory: "node_modules",
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: ["import", "babel","eslint-plugins-prettier"],
    rules: {
        indent: ["error", "tab"],
        quotes: ["error", "double"],
        semi: ["error", "always"],
        "space-before-function-paren": ["error", "always"],
        "keyword-spacing": [
            "error",
            {
                before: true,
                after: true,
            },
        ],
        "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
        "arrow-parens": ["error", "always"],
        "comma-spacing": [
            "error",
            {
                before: false,
                after: true,
            },
        ],
        "object-curly-spacing": [
            "error",
            "always",
            {
                arraysInObjects: false,
            },
        ],
        "template-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"],
        "comma-dangle": [
            "error",
            {
                arrays: "never",
                objects: "always",
                imports: "never",
                exports: "never",
                functions: "ignore",
            },
        ],
        "block-spacing": ["error", "always"],
        "no-else-return": "error",
        "no-nested-ternary": "error",
        "require-await": "error",
        "arrow-spacing": [
            "error",
            {
                before: true,
                after: true,
            },
        ],
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "no-var": "error",
        "no-use-before-define": "error",
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    },
};
```